# MD array not updating

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, filestream

I am trying to finish up on a homework project for my intro to programming class. We just discussed Multi-Dimensional Arrays.

We are supposed to design a program that essential acts as an system for booking seats on a plane. You pick a seat, and if it's available it is marked with an 'X' character to denote that it has been selected. If you pick a seat that is not available (marked with an 'X') then you are told the seat is unavailable and given the option to try and pick again. After each selection the seating map for the airplane is updated.

The problem I've been running into is that the map is not updating properly. After asking my professor for some help she advised me to change the loop but, I'm not exactly sure how I would change it. Can someone offer me some help? (info below):
Here's What the seat map looks like:

1. A B C D
2. A B C D
3. A B C D
4. A B C D
5. A B C D
6. A B C D
7. A B C D

   ```
   int row,  col;
   char seats[7][5], choice;

   ifstream input;
   input.open("plane.txt");

   for(int a = 0; a<7; a++)
   {       cout<<"\n";
           for(int b = 0; b<5; b++)
           {       input>>seats[a][b];
                   cout<<seats[a][b]<<" ";
           }
   }


   do
   {       cout<<"What row would you like to sit in?\n";
           cin>>row;
           cout<<"What seat would you like? (A=1, B=2, C=3, D=5)";
           cin>>col;
           if(seats[row][col]=='X')
                   cout<<"Sorry this seat is already taken. Try another.\n";
           else
           {       cout<<"Your seat has been reserved.";
                   cout<<" Be sure to check the updated seat chart to confirm your order.";
                   seats[row][col]='X';
           }
           for(int c = 0; c<7; c++)
           {       cout<<"\n";
                   for(int d = 0; d<5; d++)
                   {       cout<<seats[c][d]<<" ";
                   }
           }
           cout<<"\n";
           cout<<" Would you like to pick another seat? (Y/N)";
           cin>>choice;
   }
   while((choice=='y')||(choice=='Y'));
   return 0;
   ```

   }

Comment: Step through it with a debugger and you will find out what is happening.

Comment: When you ask for the `row` and `col` input and use those variables, you seem to have forgotten that array indexes are zero-based.

Comment: This example works fine, provided you take care not to provide out of bound indices.

Answer (score 0):

you need to take care of array indices.

```
if(seats[row-1][col-1]=='X')
    cout<<"Sorry this seat is already taken. Try another.\n";
else  {       
    cout<<"Your seat has been reserved.";
    cout<<" Be sure to check the updated seat chart to confirm your order.";
    seats[row-1][col-1]='X';
}
```